# let H be a real symmetric matrix with trace(HX) nonpositive for all negative definite matrices X

Tags: matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

I want to start saying that this is not a HW problem. I have been reading a paper in Diagonal Riccati Stability and while reading one of the proofs I had an issue understating its conclusion.

Let $S$ be the set of all real, symmetric and negative definite matrices.

Let $H\in \mathrm{sym}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\forall X\in S$ we have $\mathrm{Tr}(HX)\leq 0$. Then we conclude that $H \geq 0$  (i.e. $H$ is  positive semidefinite)

I tried to show that $H$ has to be positive semidefinite using the fact that $H$ is real, symmetric and hence its orthogonally diagonalizable. So we can write $H=UDU'$ where $D$ is diagonal and $U$is orthogonal with $U'U=I$.

But still didn't get it right. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If it is true for negative definite matrices it is true for negative semidefinite $X$ as well, by continuity. Consider those of special form $X=-xx^T$, where $x$ is some vector, and note that $\text{tr}(Hxx^T)=x^THx=(Hx,x)$, where $(\ ,\ )$ is the inner product.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can you explain more why it would work for negative semidefinite matrices?

Comment: Because you are given $\text{tr}(H(-xx^T))=-(Hx,x)\leq0$. So $(Hx,x)\geq0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I got this. My question how did you conclude that if its true for negative definite then I would be true for negative semidefinite matrices?

Comment: Any semidefinite matrix is a limit of definite ones, e.g. $X-\varepsilon I$ is negative definite for any $\varepsilon>0$ if $X$ is negative semidefinite. And $\text{tr}(HX)$ is a continuous function.